# Initializing an array in C/asm

Tags: c, assembly, x86

The following C function:

```
int main(void) {
    char name[10] = "H";
}
```

Produces the following (unoptimized) assembly in Compiler Explorer:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    $72, -10(%rbp)
        movw    $0, -2(%rbp) <--------- ??
        movl    $0, %eax
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

What does the line above do? I would think we would want to null terminal the string by adding a `$0` but I don't undertand why it's being added at `-2`. If helpful, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I don't think so. It seems to be more related to alignment, as the offset is basically ARRAY_LEN % 8.

Comment: Hint: How many bytes long is your array? How many bytes are affected by the instruction you marked and the one immediately before it?

Comment: Maybe you're mixed up on where exactly things are getting stored.  `-2(%rbp)` and `-1(%rbp)` are the last 2 bytes of the 10-byte array.  The first 8 of which were written by `movq`.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, ok. So it adds in the first 8 bytes with the `movq` and then pads the last two with zero from the `movw $0`. Is that correct?